# Simplify two numpy arrays by removing matching element sums

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, parallel-processing

Presume I have two numpy arrays in Python with integer elements

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,2,3,6,8,12])
b = np.array([1,4,4,15])
```

For each element in `b`, I want to remove the terms in `a` that add to it. That is, since

b[3] = a[2] + a[5], I want to return the new arrays

```
a = (2,2,6,8)
b = (1,4,4)
```

Equally, we have b[1] = a[0] + a[1], so the recursive output should be

```
a = (6,8)
b = (1,4)
```

Since no further elements of `b` can be constructed from the sum of elements in `a`, the above arrays should be the end. I would like to use this on a random numpy array

```
a = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,11,m))   
b = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,11,n))
```

for some `m` and `n` to return the simplified lists.

**Note:** Based on discussion with @hpaulj and @HansMusgrave:

There are multiple ways to get the sums to work. The order of deletions is not important. The only metric is to try an attain the *most* deletions such that the resulting arrays a and b are minimised in length.

Comment: Could you use the same element twice?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, no, the same element should not be used twice. Consider it a recursive problem. In one run, you find a matching sum and remove the associated elements before checking to see if there are any further matching sums

Comment: Efficient in pure `numpy` terms means doing things with the whole array(s), in parallel. That is the order in which the elements are processed shouldn't matter.  Also the inputs and results should match in size.  I don't see any of that in your problem.

Comment: @hpaulj, the question is updated. A parallel comparison is preferred for speedup.

Comment: The problem seems to have multiple solutions. For any `a` and `b`, you can always remove all elements from one, the other, or both and get arrays satisfying the property that no elements of `b` can be constructed from the sum of elements in `a`. Is the order of deletions important? Do you want a minimal/maximal solution by some metric? Is there any other way to select appropriate answers?

Comment: @HansMusgrave, the order of deletions is not important. The only metric is to try an attain the most deletions such that the resulting arrays `a` and `b` are minimised in length.

Comment: Sounds like a search problem.  I'd suggest writing your own code using lists.  We might be able to suggest improvements.  Those might include the use of `numpy`, but don't count on it.

Comment: When you say "most deletions" do you mean the sum of the elements or the len() of the elements?

Comment: @Back2Basics, I mean continue deleting all elements in `b` that can be constructed from the sum of elements in `a`, until it is no longer possible. Is that clear?

Comment: What if `a = [1, 1, 1, 1]` and `b = [2, 2, 2, 2]`? In that case, does one round convert this to `[1, 1]` and `[2, 2, 2]`, or does one round convert this to `[]` and `[]`?

Comment: if a = [1,1,1,1,3, 4], b = [4, 8]  would you want (1,1,1,1) or (1,3,4) taken away?  (cause you can only use those 1's once.)  the sum of the numbers or the len() which one is more important to you?

Comment: @HansMusgrave, for `a = [1,1,1,1]` and `b=[2,2,2,2]`, one round would yield `[1,1]` and `[2,2,2]`.

Comment: @Back2Basics, take away the (1,1,1,1), this would leave a smaller `len(a)`

Comment: So to clarify, we're always taking a single copy of elements from `a` adding to a given element in `b`, we're taking away that element from `b`, the order of elements taken from `a` and `b` doesn't matter, we want to continue as long as possible, and we want to choose the order of removals that minimizes something to do with the lengths: sum of lengths of `a` and `b`, min lengths, max lengths, number of rounds of the process, or something else?

Comment: @HansMusgrave, That's correct, once you found the elements in `a` that sum to a given element in `b`, remove those elements from `a` and the associated element from `b` - the order that this is done doesn't matter. Goal is to continue doing this until `len(a) + len(b)` is minimized.

Comment: This is a fairly hard problem then. It answers the subset-sum problem as a special case (`a` anything and `b = [0]`), which is NP-Complete. The minimization aspect to it doesn't help matters.

Comment: @HansMusgrave, assume then that the minimization step is removed. And that any reduction is sufficient (perhaps by taking a random sum and comparing as apposed to brute force check)?

Comment: At first glance, I'd code up a variant of a subset-sum dynamic programming solution with two modifications. (1) Check for sums to all elements in `b`, not just a single element. (2) Use some kind of a counter class to keep track of the removed elements in `a`, and combine that with a lookup from elements in your subset-sum dynamic programming table to the elements in `a` needed to create that sum so that you can mostly re-use that DP table as you start removing elements from `a`. Step (1) doesn't feel terrible, but I'm no certain that step (2) has any real benefits as the table grows larger.

Comment: Or worst-case, while it is possible to do so, for each element in `b`, throw a subset-sum solution at the current state of `a` with that element from `b`. Runtime is quadratic multiplied by the runtime of your subset-sum solver. The problem feels slow anyway, and I doubt an extra quadratic factor will have a huge impact on maximum problem sizes.